# JSP / JSTL causes NoClassDefFound error for TagSupport

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jstl

This problem has been driving me mad for several weeks now and I suspect that the resolution, once I find it, will be simple.  I have looked at every relevant answer I can find in StackOverflow but haven't managed to resolve it, so I am hopeful that someone will be able to help me.

I have re-created the problem in a very simple web app for simplicity so I hope this will make it easier for people to help.

Here is the (simplified) problem:

- I have a Java EE web app which comprises a single JSP which uses the Core JSTL Tag Library.
- I have downloaded the two JSTL jars which I believe are relevant.  These are:

  `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar` and `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar`
- I have placed these two files in my Tomcat lib folder.
- In my simplified web app there is no app library (WEB-INF/lib) so I am pretty sure I haven't duplicated the files anywhere else within the application.
- I am referencing servlet 2.5 in web.xml.

When I run the app I get the following error (edited to include full stack trace):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1223)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1452)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Here is my jsp file, index.jsp

```
<%-- Created by IntelliJ IDEA. --%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Test Heading
    </h1>
    <c:if test="true">
        <p>True</p>
    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
           version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myjsp</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myjsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myjsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Finally, for what it is worth, here is a list of files within my Tomcat lib folder:

```
annotations-api.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina-ha.jar
catalina-tribes.jar
catalina.jar
ecj-4.2.2.jar
el-api.jar
jasper-el.jar
jasper.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
jsp-api.jar
servlet-api.jar
tomcat-api.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-dbcp.jar
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
tomcat-jdbc.jar
tomcat-util.jar
```

NOTE:

In my original app I was using a version 3.0 web.xml but I am getting the same error using 2.5.

I have found that if I change the tag lib declaration within the jsp file from

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

to

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

I get exactly the same error, which surprises me.  I would have thought I would get something like TLD file not found type error without the "/jsp" in the declaration, so I wonder whether that is a clue?

If I comment out the core tags (`<c:if ...>`) The jsp works and displays the text.

I hope there is enough information here for people to help.  If you need any further clarification then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, thanks to everyone that tried to help with this.  I have now resolved the error and the solution was not something I would have expected anyone to spot.  I can't accept your answers as they weren't the correct solution but I can't upscore them either as being helpful as I don't have enough privileges - sorry about that!

The problem was this:

On a Mac, as part of the folder structure to support Java, there is a folder called

```
/Library/Java/Extensions
```

I am not absolutely sure what this folder is supposed to be used for but I had misinterpreted its purpose and had been using it to hold jar files which I would then pull in to my project through my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA).

The files I was downloading were actually libraries to be used within my web app by Tomcat (e.g. Tag Libraries).  There were a whole load of files in there from various projects at various times and I was assuming that this wouldn't be a problem as the folder was just a repository for me to store things and then pull in what I needed for my project.

I don't pretend to understand exactly what is happening at a low level, but essentially, when I run my web app under Tomcat, Tomcat invokes the JVM in order to run and within the JVM, it includes the /Library/Java/Extensions folder in its class path.

As I understand it, Tomcat doesn't use the Java classpath and has its own class loader functionality.

The upshot of this is that Tomcat was finding the correct versions of classes (such as jsp-api.jar) in my web app library, but when calling (non Tomcat) classes the JVM was finding some classes in the wrong place (i.e the .../Extensions folder) and they were incompatible, thus creating errors.

I know this is a bit vague - I have no intention of doing any more investigation to find out exactly what happened as I have spent weeks on this; the point is that when I removed all the jars from the .../Extensions folder and rebuilt my libraries from jars in another folder (I just used my downloads folder) everything eventually worked.

I don't know what the lesson is there - I am amazed at how long this has taken and how much time I have wasted on what was (as is so often the case) a relatively simple problem.

If anyone happens to have a more technical grasp at what is happening under the covers and would care to add a comment that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I found using jarfinder.com, the `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport` class ought to be in your `jsp-api.jar` file.

If not, then perhaps this is a mismatch between versions of Tomcat, JSP and JSTL.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I should have mentioned (because I went down the same route) that I have checked jsp-api.jar and there is a TagSupport class in there.  If I remove jsp-api.jar then I get a different error relating to not finding JspFactory which is also in that file.  The fact that the class is there but I am getting NoClassDefFound seems a bit weird. I agree about the mismatch but have tried a few things including completely re-installing Tomcat so am struggling to find something I haven't thought of.

Comment: Hmmm ... is there an earlier exception?  You can get a `NoClassDefFoundError` if an earlier attempt to initialize the class or some other class it depends on has previously failed in static initialization with an unchecked exception.

Comment: I have updated the question to include a full root cause stack trace.  As you suggest I think that the problem isn't necessarily that the Class doesn't exist but some other error occurs while trying to load it.  I have started looking at the Tomcat source code for some of the Classes called in the stack trace but I had hoped to avoid going to this level.  Do you know whether I could actually debug Tomcat directly to see the context when the crash occurs?

Answer (score 0):

First, the correct `core` taglib namespace uri is

```
http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core
```

as declared in `jstl-1.2.jar/META-INF/c.tld`.

Second, I don't think you need `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar`. I think it's redundant.

You should have

- [`jstl-1.2.jar`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2)
- [`jsp-api-2.1.jar`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api/2.2)
- `servlet-api.jar` as provided by Tomcat

`servlet-api` and `jsp-api` should already be provided by Tomcat. I suggest trying to delete your Tomcat installation and install a new one. Only add what you are missing, ie. `jstl`.

Triple-check that you don't have any of the above jars, especially `jsp-api`, in your own application's `lib` folder.

Comment: Thanks. I have double checked everything and it is as you suggest.  In this app I don't have a lib folder for the application it is a single jsp file. I have already tried re-installing Tomcat once but I am going to do it again.  One question - does it matter what user the Tomcat files are owned by?  In the installation instructions I have read it says change the owner to be the user installing, but I want the installation to be usable by any user on the machine so just left it.  As far as I know it just needs to be readable (apart from the scripts which need to be executable).  Is that right?

Comment: By the way - Sotirios and @Stephen - I don't have enough privileges to +1 you but your responses have been helpful.

Comment: @Auspice The Tomcat files need to be readable/writable/executable by whoever runs the scripts. If the script is executable by `auspice`, but the webapp is owned by `root`, then you won't be able to access it.

Comment: @Auspice You can always accept an answer by selecting the checkmark next to it. Do this if an answer helped you solved the problem. You can only select one answer.

Comment: I have tried a number of things now and still no progress.  The thing that is puzzling me at the moment is that, in my JSP file, I don't get different errors whether I use java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core or java.sun.com/jstl/core, either in my IDE or at run time.  I don't understand why my IDE (Intellij IDEA) isn't giving me an error when I use the wrong declaration, or why the error I get at run time is the same.  Does this mean there must be a TLD file somewhere with a URI of  java.sun.com/jstl/core? If so I have no idea where it might be.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone seeing this error after updating to Jakarta EE 9, make sure you're not using the dependency `org.webjars:webjars-taglib` and remove related tags from your JSP file.

For example, remove:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="wj" uri="http://www.webjars.org/tags" %>
```